# Horner's Rule, proof

Tags: numerical-methods

The computed value on step $i$ of Horner's rule satisfies $$(1 + \epsilon_i)\hat{c}_i = x\hat{c}_{i+1}(1 + \delta_i) + \alpha_i, \ \ |\delta_i| \leq u, \ \ |\epsilon_i| \leq u$$ Define $\hat{c}_i = c_i + e_i$ with $e_n = 0$ and $c_i$ the exact value of the parameter in Horner's rule evaluated in exact arithmetic. Show that $$e_i = x e_{i+1} + x\hat{c}_{i+1}\delta_i - \epsilon_i\hat{c}_i$$ $$|e_i| \leq u\beta_i$$ $$\beta_i = |x|\beta_{i+1} + |x||\hat{c}_{i+1}| + |\hat{c}_i|, \ \ \beta_n = 0$$ and therefore we have the bound $$|p_n(x) - \hat{c}_0| \leq u\beta_0$$ This bound is called a running error bound for Horner's rule and can also be easily incorporated into the code for simultaneous evaluation with the values above (Higham 2002
        Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms, Second Edition).

I know we need to substitute $\hat{c}_i = c_i + e_i$ and use some type of induction to get the desired result but I am not sure how to do it, any suggestions is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty straitforward
$$
(1+\epsilon_i)\hat c_i = x \hat c_{i+1} (1 + \delta_i) + \alpha_i.
$$
Rewriting that into
$$
\hat c_i + \epsilon_i \hat c_i = 
x \hat c_{i+1} + x \hat c_{i+1} \delta_i + \alpha_i\\
c_i + e_i + \epsilon_i \hat c_i = 
x c_{i+1} + x e_{i+1} + x \hat c_{i+1} \delta_i + \alpha_i
$$
and using $c_i = x c_{i+1} + \alpha_i$
$$
e_i + \epsilon_i \hat c_i = x e_{i+1} + x \hat c_{i+1} \delta_i\\
e_i = x e_{i+1} + x \hat c_{i+1} \delta_i - \epsilon_i \hat c_i\\
|e_i| \leq |x||e_{i+1}| + |x||\hat c_{i+1}| u + |\hat c_i| u.
$$
Letting $\gamma_i = \frac{|e_i|}{u}$
$$
\gamma_i \leq |x| \gamma_{i+1} + |x| |\hat c_{i+1}| + |\hat c_i|.
$$
If $\gamma_{i+1} \leq \beta_{i+1}$ then by induction
$$
\gamma_i \leq |x|\gamma_{i+1} + |x| |\hat c_{i+1}| + |\hat c_i|
\leq |x|\beta_{i+1} + |x| |\hat c_{i+1}| + |\hat c_i|\equiv \beta_i.
$$
Finally
$$
|p(x) - \hat c_0| \equiv |c_0 - \hat c_0| = |e_0| \leq \beta_0 u.
$$
Finally, $\beta_n = 0$ since $\hat c_n = c_n$.